# Django Auth ldap works only for AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN user

Tags: python, django, active-directory, django-authentication, django-auth-ldap

I'm trying to build user authentication against our LDAP using django-auth-ldap package.

settings.py

```
 AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
 )

 import ldap
 from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch, GroupOfNamesType


 # Baseline configuration.
 AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://ldap.example.com"

 AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = "cn=ldap_user,ou=PEOPLE, dc=example,dc=com"
 AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "test123"
 AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("ou=PEOPLE,dc=example,dc=com",
         ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(cn=%(user)s)")



 # Populate the Django user from the LDAP directory.
 AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
     "first_name": "givenName",
     "last_name": "sn",
     "email": "mail"
     }
```

The above configuration works only for AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN user (i.e ldap_user), but if i login using other name, authentication will fails.

And also check all my users are in PEOPLE group.

Why this configuration works only for one user?

Comment: Can't see anything obviously wrong but I found enable logging as [here](http://packages.python.org/django-auth-ldap/#logging) gave very helpful information when I was setting up authenticating against AD.  Maybe you can try.

Comment: Where do you define the `PEOPLE` in `ou=PEOPLE`?

Comment: I just replaced "sAMAccountName=%(user)s)" and it works. Thank you